# Is there a way to simplify repetitive addition in x-drive?

Tags: c++, robotics

I wrote the C++ code below for controlling an x-drive, and it looks really repetitive, I feel like there should be a way to simplify, but I can't think of any that would keep it looking readable. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```cpp
int lefty_analog = master.get_analog(ANALOG_LEFT_Y);
int leftx_analog = master.get_analog(ANALOG_LEFT_X);
int rightx_analog = master.get_analog(ANALOG_RIGHT_X);

rightf_motor = lefty_analog - leftx_analog - rightx_analog;
rightb_motor = lefty_analog + leftx_analog - rightx_analog;
leftf_motor = -lefty_analog - leftx_analog - rightx_analog;
leftb_motor = -lefty_analog + leftx_analog - rightx_analog;
```

Comment: It is good and readable code as it stands. Let the compiler handle optimisation.

Comment: You could put `leftx_analog - rightx_analog` in a variable if you wanted but what you have now is fine too.

Comment: You should only worry about this if this is in a tight loop. See how compilers optimize it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KffP13